# Как правильно передавать данные в контроллер в ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться в вопросе передачи данных в контроллер в ASP.NET Core 3.1, предполоижм у меня есть следующий контроллер:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test(int? id)
{
// Код контроллера
}
```

в данном случаи я обращаюсь к нему так `localhost..../Home/Test/5`, но в некоторых рабочих задачач я встречал вот такое обращение `localhost..../Home/Test?id=5`

Вопрос, на что влияет знак вопроса в адресе и как правильно обращаться к контроллеру, со знаком вопроса или без?

Comment: [HttpGet("test/{id}")] = localhost..../Home/Test/5 , а так вообще id - роутинг по умолчанию

Comment: Знак вопроса обозначает, что данный параметр не обязательный, передавать можно через параметры в методе контроллера и/или атрибут `[Bind("params")]`. Советую перейти на asp.net core 5, тем более что уже есть asp.net core 6

Comment: Кроме, того что я согласен с предидущими комментариями,  хотелось бы дать дополнительные пояснения. В сформулированном вопросе,  вы говорите, что хотите передать какие то данные  контроллер, из чего можно предположить что вы используете архитектуру MVC. Но тогда, непонятно что вы хотите передавать в контроллер из View, потому что далее, вы описываете код для метода типа Get, который вероятно должен что то получить для использования во View, из других ресурсов вашего сервера. Так вот,  для передачи данных из View, на сервер, нужно создать метод типа Post, и явно сослаться на него во View.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367464/Получение-данных-из-view-asp-net-core/1367479#1367479), уже задавался аналогичный вопрос, но более детально сформулированный, и получен ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос, на что влияет знак вопроса в адресе ... ?

Формат ссылки кратко можно описать примерно так:
`<protocol>:\\<host[:port]><path>[?<query>]`
При этом query фактически является необязательным произвольным набором именованных параметров. Вы можете к любой ссылке добавить произвольный набор параметров отделив их с помощью "?" или дописав в конец уже имеющего набора (В качестве разделителя параметров внутри query используется символ "&".) и это ни как не скажется на результате. Ну кроме случаев дикой паранойи авторов сайта, где все-все-все проверяется и лишнее отсекается, ни браузер ни web-сервер таким по умолчанию не занимаются, более того этот прием используется на практике для решения некоторых задач, связанных с необходимостью принудительного обновления кэша браузера или прокси без участия оператора.

> ... и как правильно обращаться к контроллеру, со знаком вопроса или без?

Тут все зависит от того как написан контроллер и как настроена маршрутизация asp.net. В вашем случае параметр будет приниматься только как часть пути.

Чтобы получить значение параметра как часть query, параметр контроллера помечают атрибутом `[FromQuery]`. По большому счету, параметры можно передавать и так, и так, но есть несколько общих соображений по выбору способа передачи параметров. Тут я не претендую на какую либо истину, уверен, что по данному вопросу мнений больше одного, но я вижу это так:

- все необязательные параметры передаются через query
- обязательный параметр передается как часть path, если он является, например, идентификатором сущности, которую запрос возвращает (в случае web API)  или визуализирует в случае крайней части пути, или идентификатором сущности включающей в себя возвращаемую сущность, например идентификатор группы каких то объектов (что-то типа **http:///.../groupId/itemId**), в противном случае, даже обязательный параметр лично я предпочитаю передавать как часть query, просто потому, что path - это путь к ресурсу с именем ресурса в конце. В случае статического сайта, это вполне реальный путь к файлу относительно корневой директории сайта на сервере и нарушать эту логику лично у меня никакого желания нет.

Также советую изучить класс [Uri](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-6.0) и поэкспериментировать с ним, чтобы чуть глубже разобраться в формате и составе ссылок.